# Reading from compressed FASTA bz2 file using skbio

Tags: skbio

Is it possible to read from a compressed file (e.g., FASTA bz2)? I usually use [skbio.sequence.Sequence.read](http://scikit-bio.org/docs/0.5.0/generated/skbio.sequence.Sequence.read.html#skbio.sequence.Sequence.read) but don't see this option there.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm looking for a skbio replacement to SeqIO.parse (e.g., with bz2.BZ2File(fna_bz2,"r") as in_f: for s in SeqIO.parse(in_f,"fasta"):) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is possible to do as follows:

```
import skbio
seq = skbio.io.read("seqs.fna.bz2", format='fasta', compression='bz2', into=skbio.DNA)
```

I'm using scikit-bio 0.5.0, but this should be possible with earlier versions as well. While I'm explicitly defining the compression type, that's generally not necessary.

The relevant documentation is [here](http://scikit-bio.org/docs/0.5.0/io.html) and [here](http://scikit-bio.org/docs/0.5.0/generated/generated/skbio.io.util.open.html).

Comment: A couple things to note: 1) The example above uses the procedural API. You can equivalently use the object-oriented API to do this, e.g. `skbio.Sequence.read("seqs.fna.bz2")`. 2) scikit-bio will attempt to guess the compression type and file format, regardless of the file extension(s) used.

Comment: How do you get this to work w/ more than one entry in the file?